# How does Postgres decide the order in which to perform cascading deletions?

Tags: postgresql

The context of this question is that I have several tables with foreign key constraints on each other. There are no cycles, but the foreign key relationships between the tables form a DAG. Most of the foreign keys have `ON DELETE CASCADE` policies but one has `ON DELETE NO ACTION` (the default, to fail if a foreign key were to become dangling).

These are the tables and their relationships:

[image: Sample tables and foreign keys]

The arrows in the diagram are meant to communicate that B and C have foreign keys on A, and D has foreign keys on B and C. When a row in A is deleted, rows in B and C are automatically deleted by the cascade. In other words, the arrows represent the direction of the foreign key relationships, not the direction of the cascade.

When deleting a row from the table at the root of the DAG, how does Postgres decide the order in which it visits tables when it cascades the deletion? Because D's foreign key on C specifies `NO ACTION`, Postgres needs to delete rows in D before rows in C (assuming Postgres's default behavior not to defer constraint checks).